# Center of rotation of a rolling screw

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

So I was just researching into the motion of a screw as you try to roll it on a surface and I observed that on applying a force/pushing it, the screw moves in a circle like a cone would if you were to roll it on its curved surface but the center of the circle in which it moves is not the tip of the screw but rather much farther away from the tip. I was wondering why that happens and if anyone could confirm my suspicions.You can observe this phenomenon yourself as well by taking a screw and pushing it slightly.

Answer (score 2):

The screw has two contact points, one on the head and one near the tip. The geometric radius of each contact is different, with the radius at the head being larger than the radius at the tip. The result is that a screw is kinematically equivalent to a cone.

[image: fig]

Like anything in pure rolling, the rotation happens about the contact point(s). These two points define the rolling axis of rotation.